# Parse javascript in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing

I have the following `JavaScript` code

```
R0; x > 5; y = 100;
R1; x < 5; y=0;
.
.
Rn;......;......;
```

It's a set of rules(condition + action), I would like to get the condition from each line. For example from the first line I would like to get `x > 5`.
Any ideas please?

Comment: [lots of] string splits?

Comment: Are the rules always of the simple form show here (variable operator constant) or any javascript is possible ?

Comment: While what you've shown in valid JavaScript syntax, I wouldn't call it "code." :-) All those expression statements that end up being no-ops...

Comment: This is either really unclear, or shows no research effort, one of the two.

Comment: @Julien Roncaglia no they are not always simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple. This apply for every line:

```
string condition = line.Split(';')[1];
```

Or you can get all conditions in one line:

```
var conditions = lines.Select(line => line.Split(';')[1]);
```

I assume that you have data splitted to the lines already, because it depends on how you read your data.